# Disable multiplayer on Game Center

Tags: game-center, multiplayer

I'm have an ios game with GameCenter. In itunesconnect game-center is enabled. There are 15 achievements and 4 leaderboards submitted. The game does not provide for multiplayer. But it appears in Game Center app. The app is displayed in the tab "Friends" in "Games in common".
How i can disable a multiplayer compatibility?